# How to convert any type array to custom object list

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I want to convert any type array to custom object list.

I get data as array of any type `getImportExcelData()`
I want to convert this to my custom type `IMaterialItemAttributesStaging`
which is datasource object for my `mat-table`, after setting only empty rows created in my mat-table

```
getImportExcelData(data) { 
var uploadedData: IMaterialItemAttributesStaging[] = data; this.dataSource.data = uploadedData; 
}
```

[image]

Comment: Show your `getImportExceltData` method

Comment: getImportExcelData(data) {
    var uploadedData: IMaterialItemAttributesStaging[] = data;
    this.dataSource.data = uploadedData;
  }

Comment: Can you please provide Sample JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Considering your type name : `IMaterialItemAttributesStaging`, I guess you're using an interface. Please, note that an angular interface name should not start with "I" : https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#interfaces

I guess you want to give the compiler an hint about your `data` type so :

```
getImportExcelData(attributesStagingItems: IMaterialItemAttributesStaging[]) { 
  this.dataSource.data = attributesStagingItems; 
}
```